# How to remove loader when entering escape in react?

Tags: html, reactjs, escaping, react-redux, loader

I need to come out from page after entering escape button , when the page takes much time for loading. I need to exit that loading when it takes longer time

For loading I am using

```
dispatcher.dispatch({
    type:'Loader',
    showLoader: true 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add an event listener i.e. **keyup** or **keydown**. When any key is pressed, just compare its keyCode with escape button's keycode i.e. 27.

In react, event listener should be added in **componentDidMount** and removed in **componentWillUnmount**.

Here is an example. You can modify logic according to your requirements.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
    }
    this.onKeyUp = this.onKeyUp.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.addEventListener('keyup', this.onKeyUp)
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.removeEventListener('keyup', this.onKeyUp)
  }
  onKeyUp(e) {
    if (/27/.test(e.keyCode)) {
      this.setState({ loading: false })
    }
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div>Loading</div>
    }
    return <div>Loaded</div>
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i am not rendering any loader react-loader automatically based on dispatching it will show loader as mentioned in query

Comment: Then you can dispatch an action on onKeyUp to hide the loader.

Comment: how can you send me the logic for onKeyUp